# Flutter TextField with currency format

Tags: dart, flutter

There's is some way to do a money format in a TextField to when the user going typing the value it going already formatting in real time?

[image: formating while typing.]

Like in the above image, while the user is typing the format goes updating the value formatted already.

Comment: Please add more details. What should the formatted result look like? What does "money format" mean to you?

Comment: Hello. Can you share the code to how you implemented the date input logic

Comment: Kevin, the code for this input format is not in flutter is in android normal sdk.

Comment: I just found this library that makes it works like a charm: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_masked_text

Comment: this package may help you https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/moneytextformfield

Comment: I rollback as SO's format is Q&A, i.e. one post for each

Answer (score 38, accepted):

An easy solution to set a custom money mask, is to use the [flutter_masked_text](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_masked_text2) package:

1 - First of all, you need add this packege to your package's pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_masked_text: ^0.7.0
```

2 - After that,  install the package using the command line (as below), or use a graphic interface for it, if you are using the IntelliJ IDEA just click in the button "Packages get".

```
flutter packages get
```

3 - Now in your Dart code, import it...

```
import 'package:flutter_masked_text/flutter_masked_text.dart';
```

4 - Lastly, change your TextField controller code from "TextEditingController" to "MoneyMaskedTextController":

```
  //final lowPrice = TextEditingController(); //before
  final lowPrice = MoneyMaskedTextController(decimalSeparator: '.', thousandSeparator: ','); //after
```

Comment: Yes, @Fellipe Sanches, this is better as i told in the top, i will mark you reply, thank you.

Comment: Package is buggy and cursor jumps around, and on some devices backspace does not work well

Comment: I also have the issue with the MoneyMaskedTextController, that whenever I type the cursor jumps to the beginning of the filed. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: `final rendaMensalController = MoneyMaskedTextController(decimalSeparator: '.', thousandSeparator: ',', leftSymbol: 'R\$');` to display the coin type on the left.

Comment: how to remove decimal ?
example : my number : 2345, 
i want to show 2.345

Comment: nullsafety version https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_masked_text2

Answer (score 42):

**[THIS CODE DOESN'T WORKS FOR ALL CASES]**

I just got it working this way, sharing in case someone needs too:

TextField

```
TextFormField(  
    //validator: ,  
    controller: controllerValor,  
    inputFormatters: [  
        WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
        // Fit the validating format.
        //fazer o formater para dinheiro
        CurrencyInputFormatter()
    ],
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number, ...
```

TextInputFormatter

```
class CurrencyInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {

    TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {

        if(newValue.selection.baseOffset == 0){
            print(true);
            return newValue;
        }

        double value = double.parse(newValue.text);

        final formatter = NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(locale: "pt_Br");

        String newText = formatter.format(value/100);

        return newValue.copyWith(
            text: newText,
            selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(offset: newText.length));
    }
}
```

This is the result of the code:

[image]

Comment: Hello, where did the class NumberFormat() come from?

Comment: Hello, it comes from this library https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/intl

Comment: Hello @JorgeVieira, the code works but with a little problem, the input of zeros  don't work.
e.g. I can't type the number "500", the last two zeros don't enter.

Comment: noting `TextInputFormatter` comes from `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`

Comment: @JorgeVieira what is the number format for "it-IT" can you help me with that?

Comment: @ParthBhanderi I doesn't really know the formt for it-IT, im sorry. But i guess you can set your country localization for the app, like this, supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('pt', 'BR'),
        // ... other locales the app supports
      ]

Comment: It is very useful, you can use in another ways. i am using this for formatting different type of fields.

Comment: how to get `WhitelistingTextInputFormatter` ?

Comment: @YogiArifWidodo: Use FilteringTextInputFormatter.

Answer (score 34):

[image]

---

Use [`intl`](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package. Full code:

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  static const _locale = 'en';
  String _formatNumber(String s) => NumberFormat.decimalPattern(_locale).format(int.parse(s));
  String get _currency => NumberFormat.compactSimpleCurrency(locale: _locale).currencySymbol;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: TextField(
        controller: _controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(prefixText: _currency),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        onChanged: (string) {
          string = '${_formatNumber(string.replaceAll(',', ''))}';
          _controller.value = TextEditingValue(
            text: string,
            selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: string.length),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You saved me. I had a problem as I was assigning the String from the onChanged call-back  to the control.text directly.. this would freeze the cursor path the beginning of the textfield.. hence writing the imputed text reversed.. I was also using the controller.text.length to offset selection instead that the onChanged String . Thank you very much.

Comment: how to change comma with dot ?

Comment: @RohmatulLaily The comma is coming from `compactSimpleCurrency`, if your locale allows dot, it will automatically be added.

Comment: This worked fine on integer but not worked for values with decimal eg: 1,234.90. It caused the TextField to stop at 1,234. Any workaround for this condition?

Comment: Does not work as needed. It moved the cursor to the end every time 

Comment: @egorikem You can change/remove `selection` in the code, set `offset` to `1` for example.

Answer (score 9):

This library works perfect for me:

https://pub.dev/packages/currency_text_input_formatter

```
...
inputFormatters: [
  CurrencyTextInputFormatter(
    decimalDigits: 0,
    locale: 'ru',
  )
]
...
```

Comment: Using this package, will move your cursor to the end to the text, so if the user needs to change something in the middle of the text the cursor will be set at the end, this behavior is really annoying. There is a open Issue at the repo.

Answer (score 5):

Updated the code from @AndréLuis to limit the number of digits (maxDigits), thanks for sharing.

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class CurrencyPtBrInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  CurrencyPtBrInputFormatter({this.maxDigits});
  final int maxDigits;

  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {

    if (newValue.selection.baseOffset == 0) {
      return newValue;
    }

    if (maxDigits != null && newValue.selection.baseOffset > maxDigits) {
      return oldValue;
    }

    double value = double.parse(newValue.text);
    final formatter = new NumberFormat("#,##0.00", "pt_BR");
    String newText = "R\$ " + formatter.format(value / 100);
    return newValue.copyWith(
        text: newText,
        selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(offset: newText.length));
  }
}
```

Use the code bellow for the TextFormField, I'm also parsing the value to double, removing the non-digit chars using RegExp.

```
TextFormField(
  maxLines: 1,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  inputFormatters: [
    WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
    CurrencyPtBrInputFormatter(maxDigits: 8),
  ],
  onSaved: (value) {
    String _onlyDigits = value.replaceAll(RegExp('[^0-9]'), "");
    double _doubleValue = double.parse(_onlyDigits) / 100;
    return _valor = _doubleValue;
  },
);
```

Answer (score 2):

To make a cleaner code the umasked value could be included in the Formatter class as a method. So when the value got changed you will be able to call it and simplifying the code.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var maskFormatter = new CurrencyPtBrFormatter(maxDigits: 12);
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: _scrollController,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  inputFormatters: [
                    WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                    maskFormatter,
                  ],
                  controller: _yourController,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    print(maskFormatter.getUnmaskedDouble()); // here the umasked value
                  },
                  onEditingComplete: () {
                    mudarFocoCampo(context, _estoqueFocus, _codigoFocus);
                  },
                )
              ],
            )));
  }
```

Here the complete formatter with umasked method.

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
class CurrencyPtBrFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  CurrencyPtBrFormatter({this.maxDigits});
  final int maxDigits;
  double _uMaskValue;
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    if (newValue.selection.baseOffset == 0) {
      return newValue;
    }
    if (maxDigits != null && newValue.selection.baseOffset > maxDigits) {
      return oldValue;
    }
    double value = double.parse(newValue.text);
    final formatter = new NumberFormat("#,##0.00", "pt_BR");
    String newText = "R\$ " + formatter.format(value / 100);
    //setting the umasked value
    _uMaskValue = value / 100;
    return newValue.copyWith(
        text: newText,
        selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(offset: newText.length));
  }
  //here the method
  double getUnmaskedDouble() {
    return _uMaskValue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [pattern_formatter](https://pub.dev/packages/pattern_formatter/install) package,

```
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  inputFormatters: [
    ThousandsFormatter()
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a very great solution to this kind of formation of money.
You do not need to implement any packages.

In this case, we create the NumericTextFormatter class and write the following code.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class NumericTextFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, 
   TextEditingValue newValue) {
    if (newValue.text.isEmpty) {
     return newValue.copyWith(text: '');
   } else if (newValue.text.compareTo(oldValue.text) != 0) {
    final int selectionIndexFromTheRight = newValue.text.length -newValue.selection.end;
  var value = newValue.text;
  if (newValue.text.length > 2) {
    value = value.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\D'), '');
    value = value.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))'), ' ');
    print("Value ---- $value");
  }
  return TextEditingValue(
    text: value,
    selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: value.length -selectionIndexFromTheRight),);
} else {
  return newValue;
}
}}
```

And in the TextFormField () widget, we can call the NumericTextFormatter class in the inputFormatters parameter.

```
           // Example 
                 TextField(
                    controller: productCostController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    inputFormatters: [
                      NumericTextFormatter(),
                      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(20),
                    ],
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13),
                          borderSide: new BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                          ),
                        ),
                        hintText: "Product price",
                      ),
                  ),
```

Comment: This certainly works like charm, for those looking for comma instead of space as used in the answer, here you go `value = value.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))'), ',');`

Answer (score 1):

Tried all recommended packages, they all have some issues, [flutter_multi_formatter](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_multi_formatter) is the nearly perfect one.

```
TextFormField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    inputFormatters: [
        MoneyInputFormatter(
            trailingSymbol: MoneySymbols.EURO_SIGN,
            useSymbolPadding: true,
            mantissaLength: 3 // the length of the fractional side
        )
    ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

some of the answers didn't work for me, I had to change and mix some of the solutions, and here is what is working with the right to left input and autoformat.

```
                    child: TextField(
                  onTap: () {
                    _iquantidade.selection = TextSelection(
                        baseOffset: 0,
                        extentOffset: _iquantidade.text.length);
                  },
                  controller: _iquantidade,
                  keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                  inputFormatters: [
                    formataNumeros,
                    BRNumberInputFormatter()
                  ],
```

Filtering formater

```
FilteringTextInputFormatter formataNumeros =
FilteringTextInputFormatter(RegExp(r'[^0-9]'), allow: true);
```

and the class BRNumberFormater

```
class BRNumberInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
@override
TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
    TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
  if (newValue.selection.baseOffset == 0) {
    return newValue;
  }
  double value = double.parse(newValue.text) / 100;
  final formatter = NumberFormat("#,##0.00", "pt_BR");
  String newText = formatter.format(value);
  return newValue.copyWith(
      text: newText,
      selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: newText.length));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
   final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
   String _formatNumber(String s) => NumberFormat.decimalPattern('en').format(int.parse(s));
   String get _currency => NumberFormat.compactSimpleCurrency(locale: 'en').currencySymbol;
    
    TextField(
     controller: _controller,
     onChanged: (String string) {
     string = '${_formatNumber(string.replaceAll(',', ''))}';
     _controller.value = TextEditingValue(
        text: string,
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: string.length),
        );
      },
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an improved solution based on the answer of @Cassio Seffrin. The problem with his solution was that it didn't enable deletion if the currency was placed after the amount. In euro we write 42,43€ and not EUR42,43, this means when we press the deletion key, we need to tell to the formatter to go delete the correct digits.

The following code will work perfectly. The advantage of this solution is that you have more freedom to modify things. And unlike the  [flutter_masked_text](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_masked_texthttps://) package, you can use it with a textEditingController from the Hook package.

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

```
TextFormField(
        controller: textEditingController,
        ...,
        inputFormatters: [
             FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
             CurrencyInputFormatter(),
        ],

)
```

```
class CurrencyInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  CurrencyInputFormatter({this.maxDigits = 10});
  final int maxDigits;

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    if (newValue.selection.baseOffset == 0) {
      return newValue;
    }
    if (newValue.selection.baseOffset > maxDigits) {
      return oldValue;
    }

    final oldValueText = oldValue.text.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^0-9]'), '');
    String newValueText = newValue.text;

    // We manually remove the value we want to remove
    // If oldValueText == newValue.text it means we deleted a non digit number.
    if (oldValueText == newValue.text) {
      newValueText = newValueText.substring(0, newValue.selection.end - 1) +
          newValueText.substring(newValue.selection.end, newValueText.length);
    }

    double value = double.parse(newValueText);
    final formatter = NumberFormat.currency(locale: 'eu', symbol: '€');
    String newText = formatter.format(value / 100);

    return newValue.copyWith(
        text: newText,
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: newText.length));
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you even tried running it before posting this answer? It does not work AT ALL 

Comment: I use it regularly in my code and it works.